# ServletOutputStream taking too long to write

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to write a large XML file(in excess of 1.5M) to a ServletOutputStream and it takes really long time, close to 7mins or so or even longer.
What I am doing is something as follows -

```
1. SOAPMessage soapRes; // Consider this is populated somewhere and we have the value here  
2. ServletResponse res; // Consider this is populated somewhere and we have the value here  
3. ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();  
4. ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
5. soapRes.writeTo(baos);  
6. os.write(baos.toByteArray());
```

in the finally -

```
7. baos.close();  
8. os.flush();  
9. os.clse();
```

I thought about sub-class of `ServletOutputStream` and overriding the `write()` but cant due to class cast issue at line# 3.
I also tried with extracting the length of the content from the `SOAPMessage` and passing that value in `write()` method at line# 6 and even as a constructor argument for `ByteArrayOutputStream` line# 4 but none work.
Any suggestion is most welcome.

NB. Forgot to mention this earlier, I am running this on a Apache Tomcat. A JUnit test has no such problem, with it this processing is very fast and is done within secs but when I run it over Tomcat, takes a long long time.

Comment: Since the source is 1.5Mb +, it will definitely take some time. There can be some optimization methods though. First of all is it a SOAP message or plain XML message? And do you want to only output SOAP body ? And right now I am thinking how to implement CONTENT CHUNKING pattern for you question. Little bytes will be written to outputstream, then displayed, then another little byte .... unless end of file is reached. Am I thinking right way?

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle: Why do you think `ServletOutputStream` is the problem? Have you identified which methods and which lines of code waste so much time? Are you certain it's not the client that's not able to consume the data sufficiently quick?

Comment: It is not a plain text xml but a SOAP message and I want the whole message and not just the body but having said that would interested to see what the solution for just the body would be. I might try to use it in someway. I have updated the question with some more info.

Comment: @Codo - Yes, I did log times after each and every line of the code and thats how I came to the conclusion that its the `write()` method which is taking time. One thing I am intrigued with is why is it so fast for JUnit and so slow for Tomcat.

Comment: @Codo - On a second look you have given me a bit of food for thought. I will have a re-look and will come back.

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle: The way you have analyzed your code, you cannot tell whether `write()` is the problem. It might spend a lot of CPU time or it might just be blocking because there's a bottleneck somewhere in the I/O pipeline. Furthermore, the servlet output stream has many layers and you don't know which one is the culprit. You should better analyze your problem so you can identify and fix the part that's really causing the problem. Most likely, the `ServletOutputStream` is not it.

Comment: @Codo - You are absolutely right. I am using a client known as TCPMon for the testing purpose and that is the culprit here. As I said earlier, when I was trying it through JUnit, it was just fine and I was quite intrigued with this behaviour and when you said that the client might be a problem, had a re-look. I have my own test client, a simple servlet to fire such requests and when I tried through it, worked abslutely fine. Thank you very much for the timely and useful hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, found the answer.
The problem was the client(TCPMon) rather than the code.